# Getting a Jabber status via Python

Tags: python, django, xmpp, google-talk

I'm developing a website using the Django framework, and I need to retrieve Jabber (okay, Google Talk) statuses for a user. Most of the Jabber python libraries seem like an incredible amount of overkill (and overhead) for a simple task. Is there any simple way to do this?

I know very little about XMPP/Jabber, though of course I'm willing to learn. Do you need to be an authenticated and "friended" user to retrieve another user's status?

Comment: For the curious: The way I ended up doing this was I decided to throw out getting the status message and only check whether or not the user is online. For this, I wrote a Google AppEngine app which checks to see if a user is online (I only check one user, but it could easily be a URL parameter), retrieve via urllib, and parse it from there. A little long-winded, yes, but it saved me having to write my own jabber bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you need to be an authenticated and
>   "friended" user to retrieve another
>   user's status?

Yes.

To get the status of a given user, you should write a jabber bot and the user should add your bot as a friend. Then you would be able to get the status of that user. [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com/) and other services do that.

Google Buzz is from Google, so they already have access to your chat status...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out Google AppEngine's [XMPP API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/) (Django runs on AppEngine, too). AFAIK you have to be authorized to check a user's status.

Comment: That looked like a good bet, until I scrolled down: 

An app can only query the status of Google Talk users, and only those that have "subscribed" to the app. There is no way for an XMPP service to query the status of users on other XMPP services.

I wonder if that means what I'm trying to do is impossible? It can't be quite, because Google does it for Buzz... Troubling.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html#Google_Talk_User_Status